# Simics 1.1.0 "run-command-file targets\qsp-x86\firststeps.simics" breaks when enabling reverse execution

Tags: simics

If the first thing I do in simics is enable the "Enable reverse execution on startup" in the preferences, and then restart it, when I try to run "run-command-file targets\qsp-x86\firststeps.simics" then I get the following error output:

```
C:\Users\jimmy\simics-projects\my-simics-project-1>simics.bat
Intel Simics 6 (build 6103 win64) Copyright 2010-2021 Intel Corporation


Use of this software is subject to appropriate license.
Type 'copyright' for details on copyright and 'help' for on-line documentation.

simics> run-command-file targets\qsp-x86\firststeps.simics
*** Unhandled Python exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mp\builds\mono-28711\core\src\core\common\simics_common.py", line 718, in enable_rev_exec
NameError: name 'run_command' is not defined
Failed setting configuration: 1 critical error in call to VT_add_objects: unhandled Python exception NameError
[C:\Users\jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Simics\simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44\targets\qsp-x86\qsp-clear-linux.simics:69] error in 'instantiate-components' command
[C:\Users\jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Simics\simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44\targets\qsp-x86\firststeps.simics:13] error in 'run-command-file' command
[C:\Users\jimmy\simics-projects\my-simics-project-1\targets\qsp-x86\firststeps.simics:3] error in 'run-command-file' command
Error - interrupting script.
simics> Windows exception 0xc0000005 (access violation) at 0x00007ff835d81528
#0  0x00007ff835d81528 (C:\Users\jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Simics\simics-6.0.89\win64\lib\python3.7\lib\site-packages\wx\wxbase30u_vc140_x64.dll + 0x191528)
Simics will now exit.
```

If I remove the "Enable reverse execution on startup" option, there is no error. Also if I manually enable reverse execution before starting running, then it works too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Simics Base that I reported internally. This bug has been fixed and will be part of next release of Public Simics.

Comment: This bug has been fixed and will be part of next release of Public Simics

Comment: I'll mark this answered once I see it fixed in the next release.

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: @simgron, what will be the release cadence for Public Simics?

Comment: A don't know about "cadence" but I know a release is coming any day now.

Comment: New releases of Public Simics have been made. I apologize the delay in letting you know but can only blame my health.